# Object references an unsaved transient instance exception even after using CascadeType.Persist

Tags: java, hibernate, transient

So even when I have used cascading I am getting an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:

Considering the fact that I am using cascading on different relationships between table saving data should not have caused an exception. But it did, so need assistance

Here is my Code-

Instructor.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instructor")
public class Instructor {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String emailID;

    @OneToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail_id")
    private InstructorDetail instructorDetailID;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="instructorId",cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Courses> courses;

}
```

InstructorDetail.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instructor_detail")
public class InstructorDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="youtube_channel")
    private String youtubeChannel;

    @Column(name="hobby")
    private String hobby;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="instructorDetailID", cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Instructor instructor;
}
```

Courses.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="course")
public class Courses {


    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH,})
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructorId;
```

}

createRecordDemo.java

```
public class createRecordDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Build Session Factory
        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class).addAnnotatedClass(Courses.class).buildSessionFactory();
        //get current session
        Session session= factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            //begin transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            Instructor instructor= new Instructor("Chad","Darby","chadDarby@luv2Code.com");
            Instructor instructor2= new Instructor("Bharath","Thippireddy","bharath@gmail.com");
            Instructor instructor3= new Instructor("Deepali","Srivastava","deepali@gmail.com");     

            InstructorDetail instructorDetail= new InstructorDetail("luv2Code","Teaching");
            InstructorDetail insDetail2=new InstructorDetail("DS&Algo","Problem Solving");
            InstructorDetail insDetail3= new InstructorDetail("webServices","communication");


            instructor.setInstructorDetailID(instructorDetail);
            instructor2.setInstructorDetailID(insDetail2);
            instructor3.setInstructorDetailID(insDetail3);


            Courses course1= new Courses("Spring");
            Courses course2= new Courses("Hibernate");
            Courses course3= new Courses("DataStructures and Algorithm");
            Courses course4= new Courses("Web services- SOAP & REST");

            course1.setInstructorId(instructor);
            course2.setInstructorId(instructor);
            course3.setInstructorId(instructor2);
            course4.setInstructorId(instructor3);
            session.save(course1);
            session.save(course2);
            session.save(course3);
            session.save(course4);


            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
            factory.close();
        }



    }

}
```

I do understand that one way to overcome the given exception is to save instructor object before courses object. But I want hibernate to handle it. I have not used CascadeType.ALL because I don't want the Instructor detail to be deleted if Course is removed.

I am new to the framework and I am enjoying learning it. I have tried answers for similar question but I want to know where is my code failing

```
error-INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: insert into course (instructor_id, title) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into course (instructor_id, title) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into course (instructor_id, title) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into course (instructor_id, title) values (?, ?)
Exception Occuredjava.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: entity.Instructor
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: entity.Instructor
```

Comment: If I am replacing cascade to CascadeType.ALL. The above code works but CascadeType.Persist throws exception.

Comment: Found the answer- CascadeType.Persist is not working bcz the function I am calling on session is save which is wrong bcz for that CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE is to be used. so to save the course object use session.persist(obj) function